# How to convert link in copy block to html links

Tags: html, regex, hyperlink

I have an HTML code block that has about 156 website links. How do I go about converting the link to an HTML link?

```html
https://siteA.com/xyA.
https://siteB.com/xyB.
https://siteC.com/xyC.
https://siteD.com/xyD.
```

I want to convert these above links to:

```html
<a href="https://siteA.com/xyA" target="_blank">https://siteA.com/xyA</a>
<a href="https://siteB.com/xyB" target="_blank">https://siteB.com/xyB</a>
<a href="https://siteC.com/xyC" target="_blank">https://siteC.com/xyC</a>
<a href="https://siteD.com/xyD" target="_blank">https://siteD.com/xyD</a>
```

The only common thing in each of these links "https://" at the beginning and a period "." at the end. I was hoping that when coming up with a solution, we could use them as an identifier.

fyi: I have not played around with regex. I use Visual Studio Code and Notepad++ as my IDE

Any leads are appreciated.

tx

Comment: What language are you using to do this?

Comment: @Evert He's doing this in Visual Studio Code and Notepad++, as mentioned above!

Comment: One more thing I reliazed when running the regex through the scripts is that some of the url have multiple periods in them. Like https://siteD.com/xyD.abc.efg. or  https://siteD.com/xyD.abc.efg.yyy-y.pqr The peiords in the url can be anywhere between 1 and 4. That were couple of the scripts were not grabbing the full url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(https:\/\/.*?\..*?)\.` should be replaced by `<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>` with whatever tool you use.

Explanation:

`https:\/\/` should be clear, as it's literal!

`.*?\..*?\.` will match your domain name and anything until a second literal `.`

The whole expression will be placed in parentheses to capture the domain name as a group and replaced in the second regex.

Comment: @csabinho.In the find, piece "(https:\/\/.*?\..*?)\." it seems to find all references of the url, but when I replace it with "<a href="\1" target="_blank">\1</a>", it does not show the extracted value. I just show's the relaced string as is. Basically the same replace string of <a href="\1" target="_blank">\1</a>

Answer (score 0):

If you press `Ctrl+H` in vscode that will open the find and replace panel, enter `(.*)\.` into the find input, enable the regex toggle, and enter `<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>` into the replace input. Should be able to replace them all at once.

[image]

The `(.*)\.` regex takes anything on the line that ends with a period, and puts the url (without period) into a capture group. In the replace, we use `$1` to insert the capture group back into the replacement text.

Comment: This will fail because of the dot in the domain name!

Comment: @csabinho I literally just ran it on my own machine, if each url is on their own line (like in the example) it will absolutely not fail.

Comment: I realized that it passes, because `.*` is greedy!

Comment: @csabinho Yeah, but performance for a simple string replace in the editor isn't very important so keeping it simple is more important IMO. Something that was going to be in prod shouldn't be that greedy when necessary, though

Comment: Of course. It makes no sense to confuse people with overly complicated `regex`es!

Comment: It's doing something different. Let me play around a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

I am new to development and this is my first answer. I do not understand what you mean by as using "https://" and "." as identifiers? So what I did is basically assumed you had a code block somewhere on your .html page:

```
    <code id="codeBlock">
     https://siteA.com/xyA.
     https://siteB.com/xyB.
     https://siteC.com/xyC.
     https://siteD.com/xyD.
    </code>
    <div id="linkOutput"></div>
```

The JavaScript file splits the contents of the code block, removes white spaces and all that and then creates the link tags you want and displays them back into the HTML file (I did that more to show that the code worked).

```
//get data from the HTML <code> block
//filter out whitespace
var data = [];
data = document
    .getElementById("codeBlock")
    .innerHTML.split(/\s+/)
    .filter(e => e.length > 1);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //create <a> tag and set attributes
    var para = document.createElement("a");
    para.setAttribute("href", data[i]);
    para.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    var node = document.createTextNode(data[i]);
    para.appendChild(node);
    //append it to HTML front end
    document.getElementById("linkOutput").appendChild(para);
}

/*
got some inspiration here:
https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/split-string-into-tokens-javascript/
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp
*/
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The original poster is looking for a solution with regex, because this can be used within searches.